# How to reduce the size of the scope bar title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uisearchbar

How to reduce the size of scope bar title to avoid overlapping

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just reduce your scopeBar `Buttons` or just reduce character in title.